# Dynamic Web Service Endpoints

Tags: services

I'm trying to find a way to use dynamic web service URLs - I want to query a RESTful server, and get some data, however the type/quantity of data changes based on user input.

I looked into the Feeds and Web Service Client modules, and neither seems to do what I need.

I can just write this in code, but this seems like a relatively common use-case, so it seems like a module solution would exist.

Comment: Have you looked at the services module? https://www.drupal.org/project/services

Comment: That's for creating web services, not consuming them as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Ahh, ok, Brain fart. What do you want to do with the data after getting it from the web service?

Comment: I have a module that consumes web services, I just use the drupal_http_request() function.

Comment: Does the web service accept parameters to change type/quantity of data that it returns?

Comment: Yes, that's why it is dynamic